# Unwrapping the wrapped column data

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a JSON file which after taking into Spark `SQLContext` is essentially in CSV format.

Sample Data File : (Notice that there isn't a fixed number of colleges per user)

```
Name   age     college_name
a1      10      abc college, bcd college, xyz college
a2      12      dsa college, iop college
```

I would like to get the above file in the form as given below:

```
Name    age     college_name
a1      10       abc college, 
a1      10       bcd college,
a1      10       xyz college
a2      12       dsa college,
a2      12       iop college
```

I know its possible by creating `UDF` in Java. But I would like to know if it’s possible in Scala?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the `json` file to `dataframe` using `sqlContext` api as

```
sqlContext.read.json("path to json file")
```

Assuming that you must already have `dataframe` by reading `json` data using `sqlContext` as

```
+----+---+-------------------------------------+
|Name|age|college_name                         |
+----+---+-------------------------------------+
|a1  |10 |abc college, bcd college, xyz college|
|a2  |12 |dsa college, iop college             |
+----+---+-------------------------------------+
```

What you can do is use of `explode` and `split` functions, you can find more info [functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html)

```
 df.withColumn("college_name", explode(split(df("college_name"), ",")))
```

You should have the desired output

Comment: thankyou for your instant revert. after a minor change (removed "split") your code worked perfectly --->     df.withColumn("college_name", explode(df("college_name")))

Comment: great to hear that @SijaBalakrishnan and thanks for the accept